# Why is List<T>.Add method not working in the specific if/else block? (C#)

Tags: c#

I have an **Infint** class with one List field. In the main program, I want to read numbers (character by character) and add them to this list.
The assignment itself doesn't matter in this moment, what I'm wondering is why I can't add values to the list of the Infint object from the if/else block (inside the first while loop). I have initialised the List itself in the class constructor. I added the line *number1.Number.Add(1)* for debugging reasons, since the code wasn't working and I've come to realize it seems to be working fine outside that if/else block. I can't seem to find the solution.
Here are the following implementations:

```
internal class Infint
    {
        public bool isNegative { get; set; }
        
        public List<int> Number { get; set; }
        public Infint()
        {
            isNegative = false;
            Number = new List<int>();
           
        }
    }
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("infint.txt"))
            {
                int i;
                char num;
                for (int operation = 0; operation < 3; operation++)
                {
                    Infint number1 = new Infint();
                    Infint number2 = new Infint();

                    number1.Number.Add(1);                              //works
                    i = sr.Read();
                    while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
                    {
                        number1.Number.Add(1);                         //works
                        if (i == 10 || i == 13)
                            break;
                        
                        num = (char)i;

                        if (operation == 0)
                        {
                            number1.Number.Add(1);                         //doesn't work
                           
                            if (i == 45)
                                number1.isNegative = true;
                            else
                            {
                                
                                number1.Number.Add(1);                       //doesn't work
                                //number1.Number.Add((int)Char.GetNumericValue(num));
                            }
                        }else if(operation == 1)
                        {
                            if (i == 45)
                                number2.isNegative = true;
                            else
                            {
                                number2.Number.Add((int)Char.GetNumericValue(num));
                            }
                           
                        }else if(operation == 2)
                        {
                            
                            Console.WriteLine("counts of num1: " + number1.Number.Count);
                            
                            for (var k = 0; k < number1.Number.Count; k++)
                            {
                                
                                Console.Write(number1.Number[k]);
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine("counts of num2: " + number2.Number.Count);
                            for (var k = 0; k < number2.Number.Count; k++)
                            {
                                Console.Write(number2.Number[k]);
                            }
                        }

                        i = sr.Read();
                    }
                    if (i == -1)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    
                    //i = sr.Read();
                }
                
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
```

Comment: "I can't add values to the list" Well, what exactly happens when you try to do that? Did you check that the appropriate line is even hit using your debugger and a breakpoint?

Comment: What does *doesn't work* mean, though?

Comment: The problem is, when we can't run your code, we rely on you being able to perfectly determine how your code is going wrong. But since you're here asking a question, we know that's not necessarily so. We're unable to delve into whatever *assumptions* have led you to a particular (odd) conclusion, so it's difficult to assist.

Comment: Just a guess: you create new `Infint` objects _inside_ the `for` loop.

Comment: `List<T>.Add` works. If it didn't, hundreds of thousands of developers would have noticed 16 years ago. What does your file contain? There are several conditions that would skip that branch

Comment: The code does not make much sense to me at all. There are checks against arbitrary constants all over the place, and there could be any number of reasons for the code not to work as expected on some particular set of data. I would recommend describing the actual purpose of the code.

Comment: Perhaps your file contains NUL characters where you didn't expect them? Perhaps it starts with newlines? Isn't that what you're trying to achieve by checking the actual byte values in  `if (i == 10 || i == 13)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Removing the various noise in your code (it's extremely low quality, if you care), what you're left with is:

```
using var sr = new StreamReader("infint.txt");
for (int operation = 0; operation < 3; operation++)
{
    var i = sr.Read();
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        if (i == 10 || i == 13) break;

        if (operation == 0)
        {
            // oh noes
        }
    }
}
```

So looking at the code and assuming what you describe is correct (if vague), that means that your text file starts with a new line, possibly two (you don't even mention your OS, let alone the contents of the file). If that is indeed the case, then it should be strikingly obvious why `operation` can't be 0 around the branch you're expecting it to be.